# How to create a unique file name?

Tags: android, file, time

I want to create a unique `singular` file that I am saving to the SD card on an Android device.

The file currently records values from a game session that are recorded `every second.`

The current problem is that the file's name is created as follows:

```
Time t= new Time();
            t.setToNow();
            int timeFileMinute= t.minute;
            int timeFileDate= t.yearDay;
            int timeFileYear= t.year;

            long timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();

            //creating file name
            String fileName= "MathsRaw-" +timeFileMinute + timeFileDate + timeFileYear + android.os.Build.SERIAL;
```

The problem is that this creates a new file `each minute` rather than just a file for the full duration of the game.

I.e. if the game was played over `09.54` and `09.55` then there would be `two` different files, which i do not want.

What can I use to create a unique `singular` file?

Note that I tried to use `timestamp` but this made it worse.

**Full writeToFile Method:**

```
public void writeToFileRawData(String data){

            Time t= new Time();
            t.setToNow();
            int timeFileMinute= t.minute;
            int timeFileDate= t.yearDay;
            int timeFileYear= t.year;

            long timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();

            //creating file name
            String fileName= "MathsRaw-" +timeFileMinute + timeFileDate + timeFileYear + android.os.Build.SERIAL;


            //creating the file where the contents will be written to
            File file= new File(dir, fileName + ".txt");

            FileOutputStream os;

            try{

                boolean append= true;

                os= new FileOutputStream(file, append);

                String writeMe =data + "\n";

                if(isHeader2){
                    os.write(header2.getBytes());
                    isHeader2=false;
                }

                os.write(writeMe.getBytes());

                os.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Well, you have to store the file name at the start of the gaming session in a variable you will then use to save...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MYValueRecorder {
        String fileName;
        myValueRecorder () {
            Time t= new Time();
            t.setToNow();
            int timeFileMinute= t.minute;
            int timeFileDate= t.yearDay;
            int timeFileYear= t.year;

            long timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();

            //creating file name
            fileName= "MathsRaw-" +timeFileMinute + timeFileDate + timeFileYear + android.os.Build.SERIAL;
        }

        public void writeToFileRawData(String data) {
            // do your stuff here, just don't initialize fileName again.
        }
    }
```

Use this, initialize a new class at the beginning of your session, then only use the writeToFileRawData method to write your data.

Comment: Can you please see the edit I gave showing my current method used for writing to file?

Comment: Edited to match your method name.
At each beginning of a game session, create a new myValueRecord object, then your that object to write your data.

Comment: Yeah do the t.setToNow is being set in the oncreate of the activity? Which means that it will not be updated each second that the data is recorded?

Comment: It's cleaner to make a nice new class do it, but you can also do that, yes. I edited my answer again, don't just initialize t, create the filename. And create a new class each time you start a new game.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file on the start and store the name in a variable, then save to that.

Comment: Yes but I need the variable to be different for every game session. I.e. if I play one game after the other I dont want them to have the same file name as it means the game data will be saved to the same file. I want every session in a different file?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding about your problem, Lets say if i played your game 3 times there should be 3 unique files with information about every session i played. Correct me if i am wrong here.

I am not sure but I think you are calling writeToFileRawData(data) method in game loop or some kind of loop  thats why it might be creating multiple files instead of one .

Idea is to create a new file in OnCreate() Method of your Activity and then you can write to the same file as the game progresses. OnCreate() will get invoked only at the start so every time new file will get created and you can save your data with timestamp in that file.